# Chequear si un archivo está disponible

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por alguna razón chequeo si un archivo está en el directorio actual, obtengo una respuesta positiva y luego negativa...

Este es el código:

```
if "parent_dir" not in os.getcwd():
    print ("No estamos ahí. Estamos en", os.getcwd())
else: 
    print ("Ok. Estamos en ", os.getcwd())
print ("Los archivos de este directorio son: ",os.listdir())
print ("Parent_dir/text_file.txt está en este directorio? ", "text_file.txt" in "parent_dir")
```

Y esta es la ejecución:

> ```
> Ok. Estamos en  /home/nbuser/library/parent_dir    
> Los archivos de este directorio son:  ['files_exercises', 'text_file_2.txt', 'text_file.txt', 'randoms_directory']
> Parent_dir/text_file.txt está en este directorio?  False
> ```

¿Cuál es mi error?

Comment: Hola Hermes, tienes algunas comparaciones erróneas porque comparas si una cadena forma parte de otra, por ejemplo `"text_file.txt" in "parent_dir"` retorna `True` si la cadena `"text_file.txt"` es parte de la cadena `"parent_dir"` simple y llanamente, lo mismo ocurre con `if "parent_dir" not in os.getcwd()`. Tengo una duda, ¿`"parent_dir"` es un ejemplo real?, ¿es decir sería el nombre  del directorio que quieres ver si es el actual sin más?¿O en realidad sería una ruta completa p.ejem `"/home/user/parent_dir"`?

Comment: El chequeo de si el archivo parent_dir está en os.getcwd()  funciona correctamente, lo que se corrobora al contestar directamente "Ok. Estamos en ", os.getcwd(). Por el contrario, tienes razón que en la última línea comparo dos strings y no la existencia de un archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Como aclaró @FJSevilla, mi comparación `("text_file.txt" in "parent_dir")` era entre dos `strings` y no el chequeo de la existencia de un archivo.

De ahí la "aparente" contradicción con el hecho de que el archivo sí apareciera en la lista de archivos en ese directorio (`os.listdir()`) y que el test siguiente lo contradijera.

Debí poner en la última línea:
`print("Parent_dir/text_file.txt está en este directorio? ", "text_file.txt" in os.listdir())`